# How to debug a Web App in Visual Studio from the first line of code to be executed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I've started my first internship in software development, and when looking at hundreds of files and lines of code, it's incredibly hard to find the first line of code that will be executed once all the assemblies and "stuff" are loaded for a particular project, but I think it would be beneficial for understanding how the Web App works.. What happens step-by-step, and for that reason I want to step through each line of code from the beginning. I took a look at the automated class diagram that Visual Studio created for the project (it was some help), but I still think stepping through the entire app would be beneficial.

How do I debug from the first line of code executed without setting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Step over - F10 by default.

Note that many types of projects may not be debugguble that way (like class libraries, web sites) or not going to give you any benefit - except possibly console application - due to event driven nature. I.e. 95% of all WinForms will start with:

```
  var form = new MainForm();
  Application.Run();
```

You best option is to ask around for tips on where to put breakpoints or at least on basic architecture. Plus understanding how default project of given type is setup would be more helpful than dubugging production code first.

Comment: How about for a Web Application?

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer web sites don't have concept of "first line of code" - so depending on type of the project you need to set breakpoints to initialization (i.e. in global.asax) and trigger rendering of the site (in site projects configured by default F5/F10 will start browser which in turn trigger initialization in server side code) - assuming you need to debug server side code. Depending on your setup debugging client side code may need to be done with browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web application, go to the index page or home page and page load event of the page. If it's a Windows app, go to the start up form. Add a break point and debug.